# Does ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW in ZeroMQ is supported in C#?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I'm trying for a couple of days to find out whether I can use a raw socket with ZeroMQ.
The application is wriiten in C#..

As far as I saw it's not yet supported, but I want to make sure that I'm right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the ZeroMQ C# binding source code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq). It does not look like ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW is supported, based on reviewing the source code.

Comment: I suppose we could keep an eye on https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/src/ZeroMQ/SocketType.cs

Comment: Yeah. Or implement it yourself and push to the project. :)